Nightwatch Visual Regression Testing with Lando and Drupal 10 shows blank white page on screencapture
Problem: When when chrome driver loads local site, page never loads and elements can not be found or tested for.
My Lando Configuration for Nightwatch works and I am able to run tests I have added the visual regression testing module and when running the test pointed at "https://www.google.com/" a screen capture is successfully grabbed.
Lando.yml
name: mysite
recipe: drupal10
config:
  database: mariadb:11.3
  webroot: docroot
  php: '8.1'
  composer_version: '2.1.8'
services:
  appserver:
    webroot: docroot
    xdebug: 'develop,debug'
    ssl: true
    config:
      php: .lando.php.ini
    build_as_root:
      # Nightwatch config
      - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
      - apt-get install -y nodejs
      - npm install -g yarn
    run:
      - mkdir -p private/browsertest_output
      - yarn add @nightwatch/vrt --cwd /app/docroot/core
      - yarn install --non-interactive --cwd /app/docroot/core
    overrides:
      environment:
        # Support debugging CLI with Xdebug.
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=appserver"
        # nightwatch config
        SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL: "https://mysite.lndo.site"
        SIMPLETEST_DB: "mariadb://drupal10:drupal10@database:3306/drupal10"
        BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY: '/app/docroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output'
        BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_BASE_URL: 'https://mysite.lndo.site'
        MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_WEBDRIVER: '["chrome", {"browserName":"chrome","chromeOptions":{"args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--no-sandbox"]}}, "http://chrome:9515"]'        # Nightwatch
        DRUPAL_TEST_BASE_URL: 'https://mysite.lndo.site'
        DRUPAL_TEST_DOCKER: TRUE
        DRUPAL_TEST_DB_URL: 'mariadb://drupal10:drupal10@database:3306/drupal10'
        DRUPAL_TEST_WEBDRIVER_HOSTNAME: chrome
        DRUPAL_TEST_WEBDRIVER_PORT: 9515
        DRUPAL_TEST_CHROMEDRIVER_AUTOSTART: 'false'
        DRUPAL_TEST_WEBDRIVER_CHROME_ARGS: "--disable-gpu --headless --no-sandbox"
        DRUPAL_NIGHTWATCH_OUTPUT: ../../reports/nightwatch
        DRUPAL_NIGHTWATCH_IGNORE_DIRECTORIES: node_modules,vendor,.*,sites/*/files,sites/*/private,sites/simpletest
  chrome:
    type: compose
    scanner: false
    app_mount: false
    services:
      image: drupalci/chromedriver:production
      expose:
        - "9515"
        - "4444"
      volumes:
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      security_opt:
        - seccomp:unconfined
      command: ["chromedriver",  "--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log", "--verbose", "--allowed-ips=", "--allowed-origins=*", "--whitelisted-ips="]
      external_links:
      - appserver:mysite.lndo.site
tooling:
  nightwatch:
    service: appserver
    description: Run Nightwatch.js
    cmd: yarn test:nightwatch
    dir: /app/docroot/core

Within the .env file located in docroot/core:
DRUPAL_TEST_BASE_URL=https://mysite.lndo.site
DRUPAL_TEST_WEBSERVER_USER=www-data
DRUPAL_TEST_DB_URL=mariadb://drupal10:drupal10@database:3306/drupal10
DRUPAL_TEST_WEBDRIVER_HOSTNAME=chrome
DRUPAL_TEST_WEBDRIVER_PORT=9515
DRUPAL_TEST_CHROMEDRIVER_AUTOSTART=false
DRUPAL_TEST_WEBDRIVER_CHROME_ARGS="--no-sandbox --disable-gpu --headless"
DRUPAL_NIGHTWATCH_OUTPUT=../../reports/nightwatch
DRUPAL_NIGHTWATCH_IGNORE_DIRECTORIES=node_modules,vendor,.*,sites/*/files,sites/*/private,sites/simpletest

Near the bottom of the Nightwatch.conf.js located at docroot/core/tests/Drupal/Nightwatch
plugins: ['@nightwatch/vrt'],
  '@nightwatch/vrt': {
    latest_screenshots_path: 'vrt/latest',
    latest_suffix: '',
    baseline_screenshots_path: 'vrt/baseline',
    baseline_suffix: '',
    diff_screenshots_path: 'vrt/diff',
    diff_suffix: '',
    threshold: 0.00,
    prompt: false,
    updateScreenshots: false,
  },

I copied and modified a sample test:
describe('ps_custom demo test', function() {
  this.tags = ['ps_custom']
  it('Test Google UI loads correctly', function(browser) {
    browser
      .navigateTo('https://mysite.lndo.site/')
      .waitForElementPresent('div', 90000, 'Page loaded')
      // .waitForElementVisible('div[class="banner"]', 90000)
      .resizeWindow(1920, 1080)
      .assert.screenshotIdenticalToBaseline('body',  /* Optional */ 'custom-name', {threshold: 0.0}, 'VRT custom-name complete.')
      .end()
  })
})

This sample test runs and fails to find 'div' after 90 seconds, which means the content is not loaded at all.
In the sample test file replacing mysite.lndo.site with www.google.com completes within 68ms produces a screenshot with content in it.
What am I doing wrong? Why can't chromeDriver load my local dev site? How do I make it functional?
